# Latex example will not run on mac

Tags: errors, pdftex

My Latex install was working, and all of a sudden it is not.  I cannot even run the following simple example.  From the error, can you guys tell me what I should google to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Cartesian closed categories and the price of eggs}
\author{Jane Doe}
\date{September 1994}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
   Hello world!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example works for me. Try to delete the `.aux` file and recompile again. I think there was an error before and now `LaTeX` chokes on this ... and why do you think that Google can help you here if you're already on TeX.SE ? ;-)

Comment: HAZZAAAA!!!!!  Cleaned out folder and all is good!  5 STARS!

Comment: I agree with @ChristianHupfer: Looks like a bug in a preexisting aux file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a pre-existing aux file, as attested in the comments.